# How to remove hidden double quotes in column values of SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Some of the column values in my table are enclosed within double quotes and I need to remove those double quotes. The problem is, I am not able to view the double quotes symbol in SQL Developer (version 4.2.0.16.260). But when I copy the data to Notepad++, there I am getting double quotes. I tried `instr` to get the position of double quotes, its returning the result 0. Also I tried to replace double quotes with blank, but they are not being removed.

Below is the data I see when copied to Notepad++. 2 records are displayed. I'm trying to take the distinct value from these 2 values. But I am not able to.

```
"Testdata
"

Testdata
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: show us your real data....in other words, we need a CREATE TABLE and at least one valid INSERT so we know exactly what you're working with. Otherwise, you're asking us to guess

Answer (score 2):

The column value in the database table does not have double quotes.

When you copy the data from the results grid, SQL Developer is adding them as part of the copy operation, to help you out. (There's probably way to ask it not to, but I can't immediately see one.) It's doing that because the first value you're getting has a trailing new line character. I can duplicate what you're seeing if I do:

```
select 'Testdata' || chr(10) from dual
union all
select 'Testdata' from dual;
```

If I run as a script, the script output window shows:

```
'TESTDATA
---------
Testdata
Testdata
```

Here the newline is lost, and copy and pasting from that doesn't preserve it. If I run as a statement the data in the query result window looks the same:

[image: Query result window]

but if I copy that data from the grid and paste it (anywhere, not just in Notepad++) I also see:

```
"Testdata
"
Testdata
```

... so the newline is preserved, and is enclosed in double-quotes so whatever it is pasted into (I'm guessing this is targeted at Excel) understands that it is a single value, including that newline character.

> Im trying to take the distinct value from these 2 values

The problem is that they are not, in fact, distinct; one has a newline, the other does not.

If you want to ignore that and treat them as the same you can trim off the trailing newline:

```
select distinct rtrim(col, chr(10))
from your_table;
```

Demo with the same sample data:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (col) as (
  select 'Testdata' || chr(10) from dual
  union all
  select 'Testdata' from dual
)
select col
from your_table;

COL      
---------
Testdata
Testdata

-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (col) as (
  select 'Testdata' || chr(10) from dual
  union all
  select 'Testdata' from dual
)
select distinct rtrim(col, chr(10)) as col
from your_table;

COL      
---------
Testdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRIM(column_name), CHR(13)||CHR(10))
  FROM table_name;
```