# Find a field with double quotes in a Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a VARCHAR2(8) field in a table and when I query it in Oracle SQL Developer, I get two different results. For example,

```
SELECT BRAND_NAME FROM BRAND WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'TOYOTA';
```

returns 1 row:

```
|TOYOTA|
```

```sql
SELECT BRAND_NAME FROM BRAND WHERE BRAND_NAME LIKE '%TOYOTA%';
```

Returns two rows:

```
|TOYOTA|
|TOYOTA|
```

The values look similar in Oracle SQL Developer, however when I copy and paste it in a notepad I got below output.

```
TOYOTA
"TOYOTA "
```

I need to delete the row which has a value with quotes, but cannot specifically identify that row because the table does not have any key fields.
I tried to search using escape characters but it was not successful.

Comment: Double quotes are showing up for me, and [I cannot reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=122d575c144af4ebb2021331d2684b75).

Comment: Did you copy and paste your statements, exactly as you ran them? If you say "yes", then sorry, I don't believe you. Stings in Oracle are enclosed in single quotes, not in double quotes; if you try the statements exactly as you show them, you will get a syntax error, unless your table has a *column* **NAMED** `TOYOTA`.

Comment: @mathguy You are correct. Should be within single quotes. Edited the post.

Comment: did you try `where BRAND_NAME = '"TOYOTA"';`?

Comment: @Yeou yes I tried it. Actually there is a space after A.

Comment: It is possible that what Notepad renders as double-quotes is in fact some other character (characters), perhaps calligraphic double-quotes or who-knows-what. Perhaps when you `select brand_name` those characters don't show on screen; to make sure, `select DUMP(brand_name) from...` and look at the output. `dump` shows exactly what is stored, whether it's printable or not.

Comment: It is also possible that when you copy from SQL Developer and paste in Notepad, SQL Developer itself adds the double-quotes if there are surrounding spaces (as you just said there are)... Wonder if there is a setting in SQL Developer that controls that behavior.

Comment: @thanuja that's weird. I can query it with `where BRAND_NAME = '"TOYOTA"';`, did you try `like` key word?

Comment: See this discussion...   https://community.oracle.com/message/14771876#14771876

Comment: @mathguy Its same in Windows Notepad and Notepad++. The dump query returned an additional 9.

Comment: if it's only for this one value, best solution will be to delete both row and re-enter the one which you need.

Comment: 9 means tab, rather than space. Try `select ... where brand_name = 'TOYOTA' || chr(9)` - this should bring back just that one row. Then `delete from [your_table] where  [same condition]`.

Comment: @mathguy dump query was really useful here. Thanks. This should be an issue with the character settings in my local machine.

Comment: The second string contains additional *new line* character. In this case enclose SQL Developer the string in double quotes.

Comment: [Related question about double-quotes added by SQL Developer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55954665/266304)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the string using:

```sql
SELECT BRAND_NAME
FROM   BRAND
WHERE  BRAND_NAME = 'TOYOTA ';
```

*(copy/paste the content of the `"TOYOTA "` string from notepad to the query above rather then trying to retype it and getting the incorrect white-space character)*

If you cannot find the correct final character then use a regular expression to match a white-space character after the string:

```sql
SELECT BRAND_NAME
FROM   BRAND
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( BRAND_NAME, 'TOYOTA\s' );
```

or `DUMP` the content of the string to find the character code of the additional character:

```sql
SELECT BRAND_NAME, DUMP( BRAND_NAME )
FROM   BRAND
WHERE  BRAND_NAME LIKE '%TOYOTA%';
```

Which will output:

> ```
> BRAND_NAME     | DUMP(BRAND_NAME)                
> :------------- | :-------------------------------
> TOYOTA         | Typ=1 Len=6: 84,79,89,79,84,65  
> TOYOTA         | Typ=1 Len=7: 84,79,89,79,84,65,9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3f8e1a944e0969118eeb18e7e26252b)*

and you can see an extra character with character code of 9 (tab)

To delete the row, you can use:

```sql
DELETE FROM BRAND
WHERE  BRAND_NAME = 'TOYOTA ' -- Copy/paste the value from notepad, don't retype it
```

or

```sql
DELETE FROM BRAND
WHERE  BRAND_NAME = 'TOYOTA' || CHR(9) -- Use exact character code
```

or

```sql
DELETE FROM BRAND
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( BRAND_NAME, 'TOYOTA\s' ) -- Match any extra white-space
```

*(making sure this last one doesn't match too many rows)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72e91cded61352034d5c598359159974)*

Comment: Thanks. Copy and pasting the value gives accuarte results while typing the tab doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Dense Rank will get the column_name and length of records which has duplicate values and different length, which can be used for delete statement. For example:

```
with BRAND as 
(      select 1 as ID, 'TOYOTA'  as BRAND_NAME from dual 
 union select 1 as ID, 'TOYOTA ' as BRAND_NAME from dual 
 union select 2 as ID, 'HONDA'   as BRAND_NAME from dual 
 union select 2 as ID, 'HONDA'   as BRAND_NAME from dual 
 union select 3 as ID,'CORVETTE' as BRAND_NAME from dual 
 union select 3 as ID,'CORVETTE 'as BRAND_NAME from dual)
 select lenth,BRAND_NAME from (
 select Dense_Rank() over(partition by trim(j.BRAND_NAME)
 order by length(j.BRAND_NAME) asc) as ct,
 length(j.BRAND_NAME) as lenth, j.* from BRAND j) 
 where ct!=1;
```